# Função javascript para gerar CNPJ válido

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Preciso gerar CNPJ válido para os testes que estou realizando, porém não sei como criar uma função em *Javascript* e adaptá-la no *Selenium IDE*.

Eu até achei na internet o *script*, mas joguei no arquivo de *user-extension* do *Selenium* e não funcionou:

O *Script* é esse:

```
//função para gerar CNPJ

function gerarCnpj (field) {

    var comPontos = false;

    var n = 9;
    var n1 = randomiza(n);
    var n2 = randomiza(n);
    var n3 = randomiza(n);
    var n4 = randomiza(n);
    var n5 = randomiza(n);
    var n6 = randomiza(n);
    var n7 = randomiza(n);
    var n8 = randomiza(n);
    var n9 = 0; //randomiza(n);
    var n10 = 0; //randomiza(n);
    var n11 = 0; //randomiza(n);
    var n12 = 1; //randomiza(n);
    var d1 = n12*2+n11*3+n10*4+n9*5+n8*6+n7*7+n6*8+n5*9+n4*2+n3*3+n2*4+n1*5;
    d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
    if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
    var d2 = d1*2+n12*3+n11*4+n10*5+n9*6+n8*7+n7*8+n6*9+n5*2+n4*3+n3*4+n2*5+n1*6;
    d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
    if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
    retorno = '';
    if (comPontos) cnpj = ''+n1+n2+'.'+n3+n4+n5+'.'+n6+n7+n8+'/'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2;
    else cnpj = ''+n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10+n11+n12+d1+d2;

   field.value = cnpj;

}
```

Comment: Voê pode postar seu código html aqui? especialmente a parte onde você faz a chamada desta função ai? Porque vc deve fazer a chamada dele para ele gerar o CNPJ, mas você esta fazendo ele gerar e jogar em algum input o valor gerado?

Comment: Oi Paulo,  entao..eu nao tenho nenhum arquivo HTML para chamar, eu uso o selenium-ide e passo o nome da função q eu crio dentro de um arquivo contendo vários outras funções javascripts. Nesse arquivo só existe funções distintas.

Comment: Foi isso que eu pedi, o trecho de código onde você chama esta função.

Comment: Não estou entendendo esse seu trecho de código que eu chamo a função..pois todas as outras funções que possuo eu só crio a função e no selenium passo o nome dela e funciona.

Comment: um exemplo de função que uso nesse arquivo:    Selenium.prototype.assertPaging = function(locator, paging) {
 var element = this.page().findElement(locator);
 var actualText = getText(element);

 var val = actualText.match(/^\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g);

 var splitedPaging = paging.split('=');

 var isValid = val[splitedPaging[0]] == splitedPaging[1];

 Assert.matches("true", isValid.toString());
};

Comment: Então vamos la, você acessa a pagina, com o selenium aberto e ele vai gravando os passos e depois você executa eles novamente, certo? Em algum momento deste processo você invoca esta função de gerar cpf para ela gerar um numero e preencher o input da pagina com os dados...Você pode postar seu código completo ai ao invés de postar apenas a função javascript?

Comment: Desculpe Paulo é pq sou novo na parte de automação.  Eu não controlo o código html da págia que estou automatizando...eu simplesmente vou montando os comandos no selenium-ide e vou utilizando alguns comandos novos que o selenium nao possui ( esse do cnpj ) por exemplo.  entao queria usar como uso nos outros comandos   por exemplo  :   Comando = gerarCnpJ | Alvo = ( campo de input da tela ) | valor = variavelqualquer

Comment: Relaxa, estamos aqui para ajudar.

Comment: Paulo vc teria skype ou algo assim ?  acho que ficaria melhor de explicar por la

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29823/discussion-between-rodrigo-santos-and-paulo-roberto).

Comment: Ja achei o erro, a função não funciona Rodrigo, Uncaught ReferenceError: randomiza is not defined

Comment: O chat é bloqueado aqui na minha empresa, pode ser por email evans_sp@hotmail.com

Comment: aaa e vc saberia me dizer oq esta errado na função ?

Comment: te mandei um email

Answer (score 2):

Rodrigo, aqui esta a função correta.

Coloque ela no seu aquivo e chame Ela ao clicar no elemento com o evento onclick, se não souber nada sobre eventos do JavaScript leia isso aqui: [LISTA COMPLETA DE EVENTOS JAVASCRIPT](http://www.marciobrasil.net.br/javascript-2/lista-completa-de-eventos-javascript.html)

A sua função só gerava os números aleatórios, ou seja, ele só fazia uma parte do trabalho, não concatenava os valores depois.

Exemplo completo, ele ira gerar um numero valido assim que você clicar no input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
function gera_random(n){
var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
return ranNum;
}

function mod(dividendo,divisor){
return Math.round(dividendo - (Math.floor(dividendo/divisor)*divisor));
}

function cnpj(){
 var n = 9;
 var n1 = gera_random(n);
 var n2 = gera_random(n);
 var n3 = gera_random(n);
 var n4 = gera_random(n);
 var n5 = gera_random(n);
 var n6 = gera_random(n);
 var n7 = gera_random(n);
 var n8 = gera_random(n);
 var n9 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n10 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n11 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n12 = 1;//gera_random(n);
 var d1 = n12*2+n11*3+n10*4+n9*5+n8*6+n7*7+n6*8+n5*9+n4*2+n3*3+n2*4+n1*5;
 d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
 if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
 var d2 = d1*2+n12*3+n11*4+n10*5+n9*6+n8*7+n7*8+n6*9+n5*2+n4*3+n3*4+n2*5+n1*6;
 d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
 if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
resultado = ''+n1+n2+'.'+n3+n4+n5+'.'+n6+n7+n8+'/'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2;
document.getElementById('cnpj').value=resultado;
}

    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="cnpj" onclick="cnpj();">
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui esta só a função:

```
function gera_random(n){
var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
return ranNum;
}

function mod(dividendo,divisor){
return Math.round(dividendo - (Math.floor(dividendo/divisor)*divisor));
}

function cnpj(){
 var n = 9;
 var n1 = gera_random(n);
 var n2 = gera_random(n);
 var n3 = gera_random(n);
 var n4 = gera_random(n);
 var n5 = gera_random(n);
 var n6 = gera_random(n);
 var n7 = gera_random(n);
 var n8 = gera_random(n);
 var n9 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n10 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n11 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n12 = 1;//gera_random(n);
 var d1 = n12*2+n11*3+n10*4+n9*5+n8*6+n7*7+n6*8+n5*9+n4*2+n3*3+n2*4+n1*5;
 d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
 if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
 var d2 = d1*2+n12*3+n11*4+n10*5+n9*6+n8*7+n7*8+n6*9+n5*2+n4*3+n3*4+n2*5+n1*6;
 d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
 if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
resultado = ''+n1+n2+'.'+n3+n4+n5+'.'+n6+n7+n8+'/'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2;
document.getElementById('cnpj').value=resultado;
}
```

Comment: Alguma razão em especial para criar uma função nova pra fazer o que já tem de nativo em JS?

Answer (score 0):

Toda função no Selenium tem que começar com  Selenium.prototype.doNomeDaNovaFuncao. Eu adaptei o seu código e funcionou aqui. Fiz com base em um que peguei de CPF.

```js
Selenium.prototype.doDigitaCNPJ = function(localizador, comPontuacao){

var elemento = this.page().findElement(localizador);

function gera_random(n){
var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
return ranNum;
}

function mod(dividendo,divisor){
return Math.round(dividendo - (Math.floor(dividendo/divisor)*divisor));
}

 var n = 9;
 var n1 = gera_random(n);
 var n2 = gera_random(n);
 var n3 = gera_random(n);
 var n4 = gera_random(n);
 var n5 = gera_random(n);
 var n6 = gera_random(n);
 var n7 = gera_random(n);
 var n8 = gera_random(n);
 var n9 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n10 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n11 = 0;//gera_random(n);
 var n12 = 1;//gera_random(n);
 var d1 = n12*2+n11*3+n10*4+n9*5+n8*6+n7*7+n6*8+n5*9+n4*2+n3*3+n2*4+n1*5;
 d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
 if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
 var d2 = d1*2+n12*3+n11*4+n10*5+n9*6+n8*7+n7*8+n6*9+n5*2+n4*3+n3*4+n2*5+n1*6;
 d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
 if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;

if (comPontuacao=='true'){
    resultado = ''+n1+n2+'.'+n3+n4+n5+'.'+n6+n7+n8+'/'+n9+n10+n11+n12+'-'+d1+d2;
}
else {
    resultado = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10+n11+n12+d1+d2;    
} 

this.page().replaceText(elemento, resultado);

}
```

Na hora de apontar para o campo do CNPJ use o comando "digitaCNPJ" que foi criado no código que eu colei aqui. Caso queira um CNPJ com pontuação, coloque "true" em valor (sem as aspas). Se for preencher apenas com números, sem pontos e barra, deixe o campo valor vazio.

Pelo tempo, imagino que você já tenha resolvido, mas espero ajudar outros que chegarão até este tópico.